# Invalid language element error in Assembly

Tags: assembly, riscv, cache-invalidation, rars-simulator

I am trying to execute this riscv assembly code but I keep getting the error :Invalid language element

This is the code part that error happend. (last row)

```
main:
        addi    sp,sp,-32
        sw      ra,28(sp)
        sw      s0,24(sp)
        addi    s0,sp,32
        li      a5,32
        sw      a5,-20(s0)
        li      a5,8
        sw      a5,-24(s0)
        li      a5,4
        sw      a5,-28(s0)
        sw      zero,-32(s0)
        call    initialize
        lw      a3,-32(s0)
        lw      a2,-28(s0)
        lw      a1,-24(s0)
        lw      a0,-20(s0)
        call    accessWords
        li      a5,0
        mv      a0,a5
        lw      ra,28(sp)
        lw      s0,24(sp)
        addi    sp,sp,32
        jr      ra
```

I just want to run this program. This is the error.

```
Error in C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Desktop\riscv1.asm line 110 column 3:         jr      ra
Invalid language element:       jr      ra
Assemble: operation completed with errors.
```

I cant understand why I am getting the error.

Comment: `ret` is an alias for jumping to the address in the return-address register; that should work instead. I forget what mnemonics RISC-V assembly normally uses for jump-to-register if you want to be explicit about it, but presumably it's not `jr`.  `clang -target riscv32` does accept `jr ra`, but I guess RARS doesn't.